Image won't populate in Excel Online - Gives #Connect! error - SharePoint
I'm having some trouble, I have a form in an app that drops UI into a SharePoint list. A flow then pulls the data and gets the URL for 2 images in the list (Signature blocks) and puts them into an excel spreadsheet as hyperlinks.  Everything works fine until I try and have the images populate in a cell using these URL's with Image(). It keeps giving me a #Connect! error in the designated cell.  I have the List access set to "Everyone In My Organization".  I know the links work, because clicking them in the spreadsheet takes you to the correct image.
Does anyone know if there's a secondary permission I'm missing for images in a list? Or any suggestions on what I could use instead of Image() to get the .jpg to show in the cell? Thanks.

So what code you're having trouble with?

It's the function not connecting properly. I'm seeing if I'm missing something from a permission.  If I put a hyperlink from a web page in cell A1, then =Image(A1) into another cell, the photo from that hyperlink will populate properly. When I do the same thing but use a SharePoint list image URI it gives a #Connect! error. What I can tell I have all permissions set properly, seen by anyone in my organization. So I'm trying to find if there's a permissions I'm not familiar with, or if it's just not possible to use that function with lists

My hyperlink is setup as the below in the corresponding cell: https://xxxxxxxx/personal/xxxxxx/Lists/Hot Work Permit/Attachments/27/Reserved_ImageAttachment_[24][Permitrequestorsignature][36][c64efa75-39d2-447a-aa9e-xxxxxxxxx][1]_[1].png

But what code are you using and why do you expect it to behave different than it does?

I apologize if I'm not understanding. To me there is no code. My flow adds the hyperlink properly, image opens in a new tab when I click on it.  Referencing it in =Image(A2), gives a #Connect! error.    If I use a random photo URL, it shows the image no issue  =Image(A2) using https://www.definitivehc.com/sites/default/files/2024-02/top-largest-independent-hospitals-header.jpg works.  =Image(A2) using https://COMPANYSITE.sharepoint.com/sites/WORK/Lists/Permit Data/Attachments/19/Reserved_ImageAttachment_[24][Permitrequestor][36][39cd0528-cd2c-42c5-b98-946e24a6bxxx][1]_[1].png doesn't
